# RX_ER peripheral not used in RMII

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, phy, rmii

I'm using this [PHY](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN8720A) and MAC in this [Controller](https://www.nxp.com/part/LPC54606J512BD100#/)

The Controller does not have the ENET_RX_ER peripherals in the 100 pin package.

In that case, can we handle the RX_ER in RMII interface using a GPIO port in the controller(taken care in firmware)?
Or can we actually not use the RX_ER signal if it is not mandatory/required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHY datasheet says RXER is optional.

It is also so fast signal that there is no way it can be detected with GPIO.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you tell me how you are telling that the signal is fast and it cannot be detected by the GPIO? Could you also tell me what is the maximum speed of the signal that can be detected by the GPIO?

Comment: On page 60 of the datasheet there is a timing diagram. After the rising edge of the clock you've got to wait 5ns till the data is valid then there is a window of 15ns to read the value.

Comment: @Newbie I'd very approximately guess 0.1 to 1MHz as a rule of thumb... maybe some microcontrollers can manage a bit faster, maybe some are terrible. I think any reasonable microcontroller should be able to manage 0.1MHz

Comment: Maximum GPIO read speed depends on what your software does and when it reads the GPIO pin, and it is a new question not related to this question. The point is you can't assume your code can catch a signal that is synchronous to a 50 MHz clock.